# kendo ButtonSize not working on angular framework

Tags: angular, button, kendo-ui

I try to change the size of the button but unfortunately, that's not working on angular farmwork. **I use the Bootstrap kendo UI.**

> I don't want to use static style, like this: height:30px

example of code:

```
<button kendoButton [primary]="true" size="large">Browse</button>
```

the `size` property not working on angular.

reference of [kendo UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonLook/)

have any idea, guys?

Comment: Looking through the api docs of your url: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonDirective/ doesn't look like the button has a size attribute?

Comment: but here wrote has a buttonSize attribute URL: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonLook/. @MathewBerg

Comment: I don't understand but why not work well. :/

Comment: I don't see anything about buttonSize there, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

kendoButton does not have an attribute for button size or buttonSize in their ButtonDirective.
(checked in their module)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonSize/

There may be a value called ButtonSize

Answer (score 0):

First you must import ButtonSize on the Typescript code, and create a variable for the size desired (*"small" | "medium" | "large" | "none"* according to documentation: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/api/ButtonSize/):

```
import { ButtonSize } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

export class AppComponent {
  public buttonSize: ButtonSize = "large";
}
```

Then you can use that buttonSize on your html:

```
<button kendoButton [primary]="true" [size]="buttonSize">Browse</button>
```

---

Another option is to write the size directly on the size property (remember to use '' to wrap up the size name):

```
<button kendoButton [primary]="true" [size]="'large'">Browse</button>
```